# PHP display user input

Tags: php, list, input, echo

Im trying to code a super simple to-do list. At the moment I'm stuck at displaying an added task back to the user. I want the tasks to be displayed right under the input form, preferably in an ordered list. Here's what I have so far:

```
<html>
<head>
      <title>To do list</title>
</head>

<body>

<h3>To do list</h3>

<form action='' method='post'>
    <label>Add task: <input type='text' name='task' value=''/></label>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Add'/>
</form> 

<ol>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  echo ($_POST['task']);
}
?>

</ol>

</body>
</html>
```

Except when I type in the task and click "Add" it looks like nothing happens.
I tried these two threads, because they seemed to be what I needed:

[Display entered text with echo after input PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046353/display-entered-text-with-echo-after-input-php)

[Simple html/php form to output on the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509570/simple-html-php-form-to-output-on-the-same-page)

But this didn't help, I even tried just straight copying the code from those threads and the same thing happens. I type in the task, I click "Add" and... nothing. Thanks in advance for help

Comment: This code works fine for me. How do you run this script?

Comment: So the file extension is `.php` and is running on a PHP enabled webserver?  Do a view source of the page in the browser.

Comment: I was just about to say "you are using. .php extension yes?" but you obviously are.... That code works, unsure what else you have I the mix that would make it not work...